# Returning a pointer from a method

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I had a certain class in my program which I used to draw various shapes and to add events to shapes as well.

```
vector<XQuad*> _inputMappedShape;
void addRegularShape(Container inputPoints, Container outputPoints){
XQuad quad;
setInputPoints(quad, somePoints);
setInputPoints(quad, somePoints);
setArrowHandles(quad, somePoints);
_inputMappedShape[currentIndex++] = &quad;
}

XQuad* getMappedShape(int index){
return _inputMappedShape[index];
}

void setInputPoints(XQuad& quad, Point* somePoints);
void setOutputPoints(XQuad& quad, Point* somePoint);
void setArrowHandles(XQuad& quad, Point* somePoint);
```

Notice that in the above code (in method `addRegularshape`), I am passing `quad` by reference to other methods before adding it to the `vector` collection.

In my main program, I was trying to retrieve the shape using the `getMappedShape` method which would return a pointer to the quad for my purpose. 
`XQuad* returnedShape = getMappedShape(0)`

I checked the memory address of `quad` allocated in `addRegularShape` method and the address being returned by the pointer (from method `getMappedShape`) and the memory addresses were the same. 
However, somehow the data inside my `XQuad` class when returned from the `getMappedShape` was not correct (i.e. not the one which was modified in XQuad reference object in the other three member functions) and instead had some garbage values. I could not find a reason as to why it was happening and with suspicion to the memory getting corrupted or something, I changed the reference object in the `addRegularShape` to pointer as follows.
`XQuad* quad = new XQuad();`

Following this, the program started returning correct values but I am still in a little bit of doubt as to why it was happening? Wasn't adding the XQuad object the correct way of adding the addresses to the collection? Or is there some scope issue here i.e when the method goes out of scope, the object is destroyed and what I actually return from the collection has now become a garbage value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the address of a local object (which will be destroyed at the end of the function call) so you end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: Is there a case when I actually can return a reference from a method? I am trying to use reference to avoid the explicit use of pointers. For e.g.: A class which might have private variables initilased with the constructor. The getter methods of the class returning a reference to the private variables such `int& getTopLeftCornerX( return _pTopLeftX);` where _pTopLeftX is a private variable of the class and is initialised with the class constructor.

Comment: A good but also a little painful tip to OP: Increase the warning level of your compiler. Try to write code that produces no warnings at all. gcc for example would have warned you about returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @user1240679: There are plenty of cases. E.g. `std::vector::at()` does. Çlass methods generally can return references to class data members; they do outlive a single call. But your case is a typical example where you _shouldn't_. Getters should be `const`, and it's better to return a plain `int`.

Answer (score 3):

```
_inputMappedShape[currentIndex++] = &quad;
```

Means you are assigning address of quad to _inputMappedShape. so you will get this address in your complete program.. but at the end of function addRegularShape(...) data associated with quad object will be destroyed as its scope will be over.. and _inputMappedShape will remain with address of quad which has no data.

Comment: A reference will refer to a destroyed object iff the corresponding pointer points to a destroyed object. So in principle you can return a reference to an object iff you can return a pointer to that object. In practice, you will want to return a pointer (or better, a smart pointer) to an object if that object has to be deleted by the caller.

Answer (score 3):

You were getting the garbage value because we were passing the address of local object XQuad to the member variable **_inputMappedShape[currentIndex++] = &quad**.

Always remember this when you create a local variable then the memory allocated to that local variable is always on stack. So as soon as you get out of the function the stack unwinds and now your **_inputMappedShape[currentIndex++]** will point to some location which actually doesn't exist.

But if you create a variable inside a method using **new** operator then the memory allocated to it will no more be on stack but on heap. In this case stack unwinding as you return from that function will have no impact on the variable **_inputMappedShape[currentIndex++]**.